# Why is my rep always a step behind in the meta?

Tags: support

Right now I'm 194.  For some reason every time I enter the meta site I'm 189.  A couple hours ago, when I was in this meta, I was also one or two steps behind.  I can switch back and forth between the main site and the meta, and my rep switches from 194 to 189.  It's not updating very fast.  Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Child metas sync with their parent account hourly, so your rep could be up to an hour behind.    It'll catch up soon!  Until you earn more rep. (: